# Python: elif or new if?

Tags: python, if-statement

What is better to use:

```
if var in X:
    #do_whatever
elif (var in Y):
    #do_whatever2
```

or:

```
if var in X:
    #do_whatever
if var in Y:
    #do_whatever2
```

Assuming var can't be in both X and Y... Is there any rule or common practice? Should I use elif? or a new if? or it doesn't matter??

EDIT: Great answers.. But can I say that if the first statement (#do_whatever) ends with a return or a break; where in its end the other condition will not be tested thus wasting the system resources or causing trouble, it's ok to do whatever.. I guess...

Comment: are you sure in the second part you din't mean `else if...`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It makes a difference in some cases.
See this example:

```
def foo(var):
    if var == 5:
        var = 6
    elif var == 6:
        var = 8
    else:
        var = 10

    return var

def bar(var):
    if var == 5:
        var = 6
    if var == 6:
        var = 8
    if var not in (5, 6):
        var = 10

    return var

print foo(5)        # 6
print bar(5)        # 10
```

Comment: `bar(5)` returns 10, not 8

Comment: @AirThomas You are right, thanks! After such a long time you are the first one to spot it? nice ;)

Answer (score 5):

If the second statement is impossible if the first one is true (as is the case here, since you said var can't be in both X and Y), then you should be using an elif. Otherwise, the second check will still run, which is a waste of system resources if you know it's going to false.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to perform both checks, you should use two separate `if`s. If you want to check one or the order you should always use `elif` because

- It's more efficient. You will save resources if your first condition is true.
- You can have unexpected errors if both conditions are true.

Performance wise, you should also consider testing the most likely condition first.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code without knowledge of the data then the elif case explicitely states your intentions and is to be preferred.

The two if statements case would also be harder to maintain as even if comments are added, they would still need to be checked.

Comment: yes, it gets harder to maintain when commands are added if the code is expanded...

Answer (score 1):

If `var` can't be in both `X` and `Y`, then you should use `elif`. This way, if `var in X` is `true`, you don't need to pointlessly eval `var in Y`.

Comment: No, but if `Y` is a very large list, then you'd be wasting resources by running a check that you know will always return false, if `var in X` is `true`.